# Stop Amazon Alexa audio output

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have an Alexa skill intent outputting an mp3 using the following code:

```
intentName() {
  this.handler.state = states.SOMESTATE;
  this.response.audioPlayerPlay('REPLACE_ALL', audio.url, '1', null, 0);
}
```

I have defined the following in the `SOMESTATE` and the `newSessionHandlers` handler:

```
'AMAZON.StopIntent' = function () {
  this.response.audioPlayerStop();
  this.emit(':responseReady');
}
```

But when I then say 'Alexa, stop' the stop intent defined above isn't called. Instead, the `Unhandled` intent in `newSessionsHandlers` is being called. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a moron, it would help if I had defined `ALEXA.PauseIntent` in the `newSessionHandlers`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Alexa SDK:

"Note: In the above scenario, when your skill is not in an active session but is playing audio, or was the skill most recently playing audio, utterances such as 'stop' send your skill an AMAZON.PauseIntent instead of an AMAZON.StopIntent."

Referenced here:
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/audioplayer-interface-reference.html